# Docker cannot run

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I follow the instructions here:

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/866#issuecomment-19218300

But get this error:

```
docker -d
flag provided but not defined: -d
See 'docker --help'.
```

Now I can't run docker and throws this error:

```
docker run -i -t appscale/appscale:latest /bin/bash
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint stoic_easley on network bridge: adding interface vethe517512 to bridge docker0 failed: could not find bridge docker0: route ip+net: no such network interface.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[That comment](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/866#issuecomment-19218300) was from 2013 and an older version of [docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/).

If you need to restart the docker daemon, you would do a

```
sudo restart docker
```

Or, [with systemd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/):

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```